# Heat equation. Find $B_n$ (using boundary conditions?)

Tags: fourier-analysis, physics, fourier-series, heat-equation

Can anyone help me with (b)(i)? I've done the first part of it. I've tried putting some boundary conditions in but cannot find $B_n$ What fact should I use?

> ￼An infinite slab of material, of constant thermoconductivity $\kappa$, occupies the region of $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $0 \leq x \leq a$. Initially the temperature $T(x,t)$ of  the slab is given by
>   $$T(x,0) = 0.$$
>   Subsequently the face at $x = 0$ is kept at zero temperature and the face at $x = a$ is kept at unit temperature.
>
> (a) Write down the boundary conditions satisfied by $T$. Show that
>   $$U(x,t) = T(x,t) - \frac{x}{a},$$
>   satisfies the heat equation
>   $$\frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{t}} = \kappa\,\frac{\partial^2{U}}{\partial{x^2}},$$
>   and deduce the boundary conditions on $U$.
>
> (b) (i) Show that, for $t > 0$,
>   $$T(x,t) = \frac{x}{a} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n \exp\left(-\frac{n^2 \pi^2 \kappa t}{a^2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right)$$
>   and give an explicit expression for the constants $B_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the initial condition on $T$ is $T(x,0)=0$.  But the equation you are really solving is for $U$, which has initial condition $U(x,0)=-x/a$.  Thus, assuming you could derive

$$U(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n e^{-n^2 \pi^2 \kappa t/a^2} \sin{\left ( \frac{n \pi x}{a}\right )}$$

then

$$U(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sin{\left ( \frac{n \pi x}{a}\right )}$$

which means that $u$ is being represented by a Fourier sine series and the $B_n$ are given by corresponding Fourier sine coefficients.  These are given by

$$B_n = \frac{2}{a} \int_0^a dx \, \left ( -\frac{x}{a} \right ) \sin{\left ( \frac{n \pi x}{a}\right )} = -\frac{2}{a^2} \int_0^a dx \; x \sin{\left ( \frac{n \pi x}{a}\right )}$$

I'll leave it to you to evaluate the integral.

Comment: That makes sense! I've been taught fourier series first and we just started learning about heat equation. I struggled to see the relationship between those two. Do you mind explaining how they're related? Other than cases like this?

Comment: @user120227: The boundary values provide the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions which become the Fourier series expansion.  Here, the zero BC's at either end imply a sine solution.  The initial conditions therefore provide the coefficients of the Fourier series as I demonstrated.  This of course works when you have finite BC's because you have a second-order equation in $x$.

Comment: THank you. This sounds stupid but why do I put in $U(x,0)$ in the place of where $f(x)$ goes for fourier series?

Comment: @user120227: All I can say is, exactly.  You can say that the initial condition is $U(x,0)=f(x)$ if that makes you more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Fourier coefficients of the initial data  $U(x,0)=-x/a$  will be the desired constants
$$
\begin{gather}
B_n=\frac{2}{a}\int\limits_0^a U(x,0)\sin{\biggl(\frac{n{\pi}x}{a}\biggr)}dx=
-\frac{2}{a^2}\int\limits_0^a x\sin{\biggl(\frac{n{\pi}x}{a}\biggr)}dx=\\
=\frac{2}{an\pi}\int\limits_0^a x\,d\cos{\biggl(\frac{n{\pi}x}{a}\biggr)}=
\frac{2}{an\pi}x\cos{\biggl(\frac{n{\pi}x}{a}\biggr)}\biggr|_0^a-\frac{2}{an\pi}
\int\limits_0^a \cos{\biggl(\frac{n{\pi}x}{a}\biggr)}dx=\\
=\frac{2}{n\pi}\cos{(n\pi)}-\frac{2}{n^2{\pi}^2}\sin{\biggl(\frac{n{\pi}x}{a}\biggr)}
\biggr|_0^a=\frac{2(-1)^n}{n\pi}.
\end{gather}
$$

Comment: @Ron Gordon: Thanx Ron. This was a typical TeX-copy-paste slip of the keyboard. If I had noticed that you posted your answer I would not have posted mine.